# Symfony FatalThrowableError : Call to a member function getId() on null

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, sylius

I am doing an e-commerce site, and in the end I realized a bug when modifying the informations of the customers informations:

the error is as follows:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Error: "Call to a member function getId() on null" 
at C:\wamp64\www\caviar-pro\src\Controller\CustomerController.php line 339
```

Here is the part of the code that is problematic:
[image]

The complete code is the following:

```
public function updateAction(Request $request): Response
{
    $configuration = $this->requestConfigurationFactory->create($this->metadata, $request);
    $this->isGrantedOr403($configuration, ResourceActions::UPDATE);
    $resource = $this->findOr404($configuration);
    $form = $this->resourceFormFactory->create($configuration, $resource);
    $oldInfo = clone $resource;
    $oldAddressInfo = $oldInfo->getDefaultAddress() ? clone $oldInfo->getDefaultAddress() : null;

    if (in_array($request->getMethod(), ['POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH'], true) && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
        /** @var CustomerInterface $resource */
        $resource = $form->getData();
        $defaultAddress = $resource->getDefaultAddress();
        if (!$defaultAddress->getId()) {
            $defaultAddress->setFirstName($resource->getFirstName());
            $defaultAddress->setLastName($resource->getLastName());
        }

        /** @var ResourceControllerEvent $event */
        $event = $this->eventDispatcher->dispatchPreEvent(ResourceActions::UPDATE, $configuration, $resource);
        if ($event->isStopped() && !$configuration->isHtmlRequest()) {
            throw new HttpException($event->getErrorCode(), $event->getMessage());
        }
        if ($event->isStopped()) {
            $this->flashHelper->addFlashFromEvent($configuration, $event);
            if ($event->hasResponse()) {
                return $event->getResponse();
            }
            return $this->redirectHandler->redirectToResource($configuration, $resource);
        }
        try {
            $this->resourceUpdateHandler->handle($resource, $configuration, $this->manager);
            $valueChangedPersonnalInfo = $this->compareCustomer($oldInfo, $resource);
            $valueChangedAddress = $oldAddressInfo ? $this->compareAddressCustomer($oldAddressInfo, $resource->getDefaultAddress()) : [];
            $valueChanged = array_merge($valueChangedPersonnalInfo, $valueChangedAddress);

            /*sending email according to template bo*/
            /** @var Email $email */
            $email = $this->manager->getRepository('App\Entity\Email\Email')->findOneByCode(MailerManager::ACCOUNT_MODIFICATION_MAILER_CODE);
            $user = $this->getUser();
            $emailManager = $this->emailManager->letterParagraphBy($email->getContent(), $email, $user->getCustomer());
            $emailToSend = $this->renderView('@SyliusShop/Email/userInfoChange.html.twig', [
              'infoChanged' => $valueChanged,
              'email' => $email,
              'emailManager' => $emailManager,
            ]);

            $emailFrom = [$email->getFromEmail() => $email->getFromName()];
            $this->mailerManager->sendMail($resource->getEmail(), $email->getSubject(), $emailToSend, $emailFrom);

        } catch (UpdateHandlingException $exception) {
            if (!$configuration->isHtmlRequest()) {
                return $this->viewHandler->handle(
                    $configuration,
                    View::create($form, $exception->getApiResponseCode())
                );
            }
            $this->flashHelper->addErrorFlash($configuration, $exception->getFlash());
            return $this->redirectHandler->redirectToReferer($configuration);
        }
        $postEvent = $this->eventDispatcher->dispatchPostEvent(ResourceActions::UPDATE, $configuration, $resource);
        if (!$configuration->isHtmlRequest()) {
            $view = $configuration->getParameters()->get('return_content', false) ? View::create($resource, Response::HTTP_OK) : View::create(null, Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
            return $this->viewHandler->handle($configuration, $view);
        }
        $this->flashHelper->addSuccessFlash($configuration, ResourceActions::UPDATE, $resource);
        if ($postEvent->hasResponse()) {
            return $postEvent->getResponse();
        }
        return $this->redirectHandler->redirectToResource($configuration, $resource);
    }
    if (!$configuration->isHtmlRequest()) {
        return $this->viewHandler->handle($configuration, View::create($form, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST));
    }
    $initializeEvent = $this->eventDispatcher->dispatchInitializeEvent(ResourceActions::UPDATE, $configuration, $resource);
    if ($initializeEvent->hasResponse()) {
        return $initializeEvent->getResponse();
    }
    $carrousels =  $this->manager->getRepository(Carrousel::class)->findOneBy(['code' => 'my_account_carrousel', 'enabled' => true]);

    $view = View::create()
        ->setData([
            'configuration' => $configuration,
            'metadata' => $this->metadata,
            'resource' => $resource,
            $this->metadata->getName() => $resource,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'carrousels' => $carrousels,
        ])
        ->setTemplate($configuration->getTemplate(ResourceActions::UPDATE . '.html'))
    ;
    return $this->viewHandler->handle($configuration, $view);
}
```

If someone could tell me the solution to my problem I'm interested because I'm stuck on this part of my site for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `!$defaultAddress->getId()`, id will always exists except the entity is not yet persisted or null.
 On you case, `$defaultAddress` is null. (dump the variable to see).

I think, you should do something like:

```
if (!$defaultAddress) {
    $defaultAddress = new AddressObject(); //change this to your address class
    $defaultAddress->setFirstName($resource->getFirstName());
    $defaultAddress->setLastName($resource->getLastName());
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, indeed I just follow your instructions and it's perfect :)